# How do I create/edit a YAML Release pipeline on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have a build pipeline in YAML and it is working fine.  I now want to create the release pipeline.

I have created the pipeline using the UI and I have added a task (which happens to be an AZURUE CLI Task), When U use the UI to add variables to the command I get the error.

```
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
```

reading the documentation I need to add a

```
- variables:
```

section to the YAML, but I cannot find where to directly edit the release pipeline YAML.  (The build pipeline YAML is in my code)

How do I edit that YAML Release Pipeline?

Alternatively, how do I add variables to this release pipeline using the UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I add variables to this release pipeline using the UI

Edit your release pipeline and you will find the `Variables` tab just right beside `Tasks`:

[image]

Click `Add` to add new variables.

Or if you are using the variable group:

[image]

> How do I edit that YAML Release Pipeline?

To enable YAML Release Pipeline, you need to enable `Multi-stage YAML pipelines` in `Preview features`:

[image]

Check [Multi-stage YAML pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, @yang I didn't mention in my original post that I have the variables defined in a variable group.  Will that make a difference?

Comment: No, it makes no difference, the variable group can even make it more convenient to add variables in fact. But please make sure you have linked the specific variable group to your release pipeline. You can see it in my edited post.

Comment: That's what I thought, but in this case, it must.  I started using pipeline variables and it started working.  Must be a defect in the current version we are running of DevOps.

Comment: That's wierd since i have tested the variable group in my project, maybe it's the version like you said. Anyway, glad to know your problem has been resolved, you can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helps, thanks!